# RiotJS tag inside yield not updating

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I have a problem when using yield and updating tag in, see example http://codepen.io/Pysta/pen/pEyoBY

```
<script type="riot/tag">
  <maintag>

    <yieldtag name='yield_tag'>
      <select>
        <option each={ items }>{ value }</option>
      </select>

    </yieldtag>


    var self = this;
    self.items = [
        {value:1},
        {value:2},
            {value:3},
        {value:4}
    ];
        self.items = [];

    this.on('mount', function () {
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
      oReq.open("GET", "/api/category/0");
      oReq.send();
    });

    function reqListener(e) {
        console.log('load');
        self.items = [
        {value:1},
        {value:2},
            {value:3},
        {value:4}
      ];
        self.update(); 
    }

  </maintag>
</script>


<script type="riot/tag">
  <yieldtag>
    <yield />
  </yieldtag>
</script>

<maintag></maintag>
```

If I load data straight away (comment line with "self.items = [];") it works as it's supposed to, but when I make a request and update it asynchronously nothing changes.

If I remove yieldtag from inside maintag, it works.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `each={ items }` to `each={ parent.items }` it will work as expected

The confusion with `<yield />` is that you're writing your template logic in the `<maintag>`, but once the components are mounted, your code is actually running in `<yieldtag>`. The `items` array exists in the context of the `<maintag>`, which is `<yieldtag>`'s parent after mounting.

For more on nesting tags, see the [Riot docs](http://riotjs.com/guide/#nested-tags)

Comment: Yup, we all get into that weirdness some day when doing Riot…